# How to get notified whenever an application access the contact app

Tags: android

I want that whenever any system or user application access the system contact app, my app get notified about that somehow. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not possible from an ordinary SDK app. Any app can access the Contacts `ContentProvider` as they wish (assuming that they have permission), and there is no way for your app to find out about that.

You are welcome to create a custom Android fork that contains your desired capability and install that on whatever devices you are able.